# INSERT INTO - ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql, mysqli

I got this query in a loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    INSERT INTO restaurant_views (date, restaurant_id, views) VALUES ('{$current_date}', '{$row['id']}', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views=views+1
}
```

What this code should do is to update the column **views** inside the table **restaurant_views**.
The problem is that it doesn't check if date and restaurant_id is duplicate, it just checks if the primary column in the database is duplicate.

Here is a screenshot of the table:
[image]

As you can see, both **date** and **restaurant_id** is unique, but what this code give me is this:

[image]

The query was looped 7 times, as you can see in the views. This is wrong.
What I want is 7 different rows with 1 view in each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want uniqueness on the restaurant id/date then you need a unique index/constraint on those columns:

```
create unique index idx_restaurant_views_2 on restaurant_views(restaurant_id, date)
```

Then your code should work.